# Xcode: How do you save an editable Object Array and use it to populate a table view?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I am attempting to create a setup where an initially empty array of the "Item" class populates a tableView and a button click appends a new object to the array and inserts the cell. It all works fine but the data is obviously not saved, so whenever the app is restarted the array is empty again. I need a way to save the array (preferably in the buttonPress method because thats where a new element is appended) and load it up so upon restart the tableView is populated by a non empty array which can be continually updated by appended values. This is what I have so far:

```
class Item {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var itemView: UITableView!
var newArray = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = myarray[myIndex].name
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

func insertNewCell() {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        itemView.beginUpdates()
        itemView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        itemView.endUpdates()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newArray.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell",for:indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = newArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
        newArray.append(Item(name:"newitem"))
        insertNewCell()
    }
}
```

I tried follwing a tutorial on UserDefaults but I couldnt get the code to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use user defaults  with `codable` to store object array

confirm your class to `codable`

```
struct Item: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

then on button tap

```
@IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
        newArray.append(Item(name:"newitem"))
        insertNewCell()
        //Storing Items
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newArray) {
             UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "items")
           }
    }
```

And in `viewDidLoad()` you load array from user defaults

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = myarray[myIndex].name
do {
    let storedObjItem = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")
    newArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: storedObjItem as! Data)
    print("Retrieved items: \(newArray)")
   itemView.reloadData()
} catch let err {
    print(err)
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume when you say "JSONEncoder().encode(items)" items is referring to newArray, but what is "storedItems" meant to reference? Xcode raises the "use of unresolved identifier" for both items and storedItems, and I am unsure which the latter is meant to refer to.

Comment: check it now ... hopefully it will help you ... to show stored objects in tableView ... let me know if you face any difficulty